# Sas Results Viewer - Start at top of new output

Tags: sas, output

This is another usability oriented question for me...

Is there a way to have the results viewer "auto-position" itself at the top of the most recent output when something new is submitted?

Sometimes the results viewer shows the bottom of the just-generated table. Sometimes, it shows the top of a table, but not of the "topmost" table (i.e. in the middle of new results).

This behavior is akin to surfing the web and having chrome open a new webpage at the bottom... it really doesn't make sense and takes time away from viewing the results while trying to find the actual top of the new results, which can sometimes be very long and mixed up with other previous results.

A partial workaround, is to have the logs/results viewer clear during each run, which at least makes it easy to page to the top of the current results, but I still have to actually page up, which just seems silly. Here is what I use to clear logs and the output viewer from the code. Is there a better set of commands to use?

```
*Clear prior run's result viewer list and log window*;
ods html close; /* close previous */
DM log "OUT;CLEAR;LOG;CLEAR;" log continue ;
DM log 'next results; clear; cancel;' whostedit continue ;
ods html; /* open new */
```

Comment: What version of SAS are you using. SAS Studio doesn't do this, so its a behaviour thats been noted at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can! By understanding that:

- `ODS HTML` destination generates HTML source that has the default anchor `<A``NAME=IDX#n>` before each proc's output.  The anchor name prefix can be altered with the `ODS HTML ANCHOR=` option.
- `Proc TEMPLATE` can be used to create a custom style that utilizes a style attribute such as `POSTHTML` to inject a HTML snippet into the destination that is JavaScript code.
- The injected JavaScript can assign `location.hash` to the expected initial anchor name.  This will force the browser to navigate to that anchor.

Example:

```
proc template;
  define style topnav;       /* name of style to specify when opening ODS HTML */
    parent=styles.htmlblue;  /* name of style to use for thematic desire */

    /* JavaScript to be injected into destination */
    style body from body /
      posthtml="<script>location.hash='#IDX';</script>";  
    end;
run;

ods html 
  path="C:\temp" 
  body="sample.html"
  style=topnav          /* specify the custom style */
;

proc print data=sashelp.cars;
run;

proc print data=sashelp.class;
run;

ods html close;
```